# Trigger build for PR after Github comment

Tags: github, continuous-integration

My use case is that I have an open-source repository where other developers fork it and then open PRs from their own forks. I would like to run my CI setup only after I have acknowledged the PR (to prevent spam). Ideally I should be able to go `[CI RUN]` as a comment and then the PR I commented on gets build.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a job that queries the GitHub API, they give you full access to pull request comments via:

https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/comments/

I know it says "issues" but the documentation states you may also use this API for PR comments by passing a PR number instead of an issue number. This works because the union of PR and Issue numbers are unique per GitHub repository.