# Github repo: Trigger pull-request build on azure pipelines if and only if a maintainer of the repo adds a comment '[build]' in the PR-dicsussion

Tags: github, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cicd

Essentially what the subject says. I found this previous question but it doesn't seem very elegant:

[Trigger build for PR after Github comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43640067/trigger-build-for-pr-after-github-comment)

Have things improved in the meantime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually yes, there is already a better option to use [comment triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#comment-triggers) to control the automated PR build, especially for the [contributions from a forked source repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/github?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#contributions-from-forks).

[image]
[image]

The automated PR build will not be triggered until repository owners and collaborators with `Write` permission comment on the pull request with `/AzurePipelines run` or `/AzurePipelines run <pipeline-name>`.

[image]

Hope the information could help.

Comment: In case someone wonders the very first screenshot is from your organization's settings in Azure (the button to access it is at the bottom left corner of your organization root-page)